# Disable module while running command

Tags: 6, drush

I have a custom drush command that does some pretty heavy node creation etc. I would like to disable certain modules only for the duration of the script to improve their performance.

I can not do a `drush dis module_name` before running my command because I need the modules to be active on the site while the script is running, but not active for the runtime environment of the current command.

I would rather not have to hack core, but from what I can see, I'm probably going to need to alter something in either `module_list()` or `drupal_load()` since neither of them have any hooks.

Is there any way to do what I'm after without hacking core?

Comment: What about [module_disable()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_disable/7)?

Comment: @jonhattan That will disable the module in the system table. I do not want to disable the module for the live running site. What I need is to disable (not load) a certain list of modules which is determined at runtime, presumably early in the bootstrap.

Comment: So you want to not fire some hooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution that I came up with after looking around in core's code. It seems to work as expected.

```
$module_list = module_list();
if (isset($module_list['token'])) {
    unset($module_list['token']);
}
// Reset the list to our new list of modules!
module_list(false, false, false, $module_list);
// Force to regenerate the stored list of hook implementations.
module_implements('', false, true);
```

Comment: This stores the hooks to the cache in database, and affects all users untill next cache clear. Try hook_module_implements_alter() in your drush command. A sneaky way to implement a hook in a module is to use the prefix of a module that you know is enabled --and doesn't implement that hook--, for example: system_module_implements_alter()

Comment: @jonhattan I don't believe you are correct about this effecting all users and being stored in the db. Both of the function calls only store their cached values in a static variable. Unless there is another module that calls these and updates the db cache for every page call (highly unlikely in my opinion) this change will only be in-memory for the current request, exactly what I want.

Comment: yep. module_implements() uses a static cache AND database cache. You're asking the function to reset the database cache (third argument = true). OTOH it seems my recomendation for hook_module_implements_alter() is neither adequate.

Comment: Oh I see the cache is not written to database in module_implements() but module_implements_write_cache(), that is called from drupal_page_footer(), so your solution doesn't affect other threads. Nice!